# Is there a way to combine results from two IQueryable<T> using NHibernate & Linq?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have two separate queries that both return the same IQueryable, and I'd like to combine them prior to projection.  It looks like neither Union or Concat are implemented in Linq to NHibernate?  Does anyone know how I might go about achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible. You'll **have** to do it on the client.

Example:

```
var allItems = queryable1.AsEnumerable().Concat(queryable2)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Diago Mijelshon gives a good answer, but I would like to add that depending on what you're doing with the data, you may need to first cast it to an array or list so that NHibernate doesn't try to do any funny stuff with your operations.

I've used Entity Framework for years and I'm well familiar with this, and I've only used NHibernate a little bit, but the two tools appear to be similar in this regard.